# d3.js histogram with positive and negative values

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I can't figure out how to properly create a histogram where there are both positive and negative values in the data array.

I've used the histogram example here http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3048450 as a base, and while the x axis values and ticks are correct, the bars are out to lunch.

#### Data

```
var values = [-15, -20, -22, -18, 2, 6, -26, -18, -15, -20, -22, -18, 2, 6, -26, -18];
```

#### X Scale

```
var x0 = Math.max(-d3.min(values), d3.max(values));
            
var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([-x0, x0])
    .range([0, width])
    .nice();
```

Check the jfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/tNdJj/2/

I assume it's something missing from the "rect" creations but I am not seeing it.

Comment: So what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/tNdJj/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is that the demo code is overly optimistic, assuming that its input is positive:

```
bar.append("rect")
    .attr("x", 1)
    // .attr("width", x(data[0].dx) - 1)   // Does the wrong thing for negative buckets.
    .attr("width", x(data[0].x  + data[0].dx) - 1)
    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.y); });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tNdJj/46/

Answer (score 12):

Using the example of histogram from the following question: [Bar chart with negative values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10127402/bar-chart-with-negative-values)

I inversed x and y and adapted the display. Now you have a nice basis.

[image]

Here is the corresponding jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/chrisJamesC/tNdJj/4/

Here is the relevant code:

```
var data = [-15, -20, -22, -18, 2, 6, -26, -18];

var margin = {top: 30, right: 10, bottom: 10, left: 30},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var y0 = Math.max(Math.abs(d3.min(data)), Math.abs(d3.max(data)));

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([-y0, y0])
    .range([height,0])
    .nice();

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(d3.range(data.length))
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .2);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
  .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", function(d) { return d < 0 ? "bar negative" : "bar positive"; })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(Math.max(0, d)); })
    .attr("x", function(d, i) { return x(i); })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return Math.abs(y(d) - y(0)); })
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand());

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .call(yAxis);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
  .append("line")
    .attr("y1", y(0))
    .attr("y2", y(0))
    .attr("x1", 0)
    .attr("x2", width);
```

**Note:** For simple visualizations like this, I would recommand using [nvd3.js](http://nvd3.org/examples/discreteBar.html)

Comment: very pretty, but it's not a histogram.

Comment: Ho, that's true. Thanks for noticing it.

Comment: Thanks for the link to nvd3.js (the link is broken...the working one is http://nvd3.org/) - I found the exact chart I needed with their re-usable chart examples.

Comment: Thanks @EricD.Brown. I have fixed the link.