# How do I create a column chart with negative values?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to essentially rotate [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2368837) horizontal bar chart into a vertical bar chart,  but can't figure out how to do so. I can create a normal column chart, but once I try to put in the negative values and compute the y and height, all hell breaks loose. Here's [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pYZn8/3/). (At least I was able to create the y-axis (I think).)

What am I doing wrong here?

```
var data = [{"letter":"A",'frequency':10},{"letter":"B","frequency":-5},{"letter":"C","frequency":7}];

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40}, width = 750 - margin.left - margin.right, height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(x)
            .orient("bottom");
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(y)
            .orient("left");

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
   .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
var x0 = Math.max(-d3.min(data), d3.max(data));
     x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.letter; }));
     y.domain([d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.frequency; }), d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.frequency; })]);

  svg.append("g")
     .attr("class", "x axis")
     .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
     .call(xAxis);
  svg.append("g")
     .attr("class", "y axis")
     .call(yAxis);

  svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data).enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function(d, i) { return x(d.letter); })
      .attr("y", function(d, i) { return x(Math.min(0, d.frequency));})
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("height", function(d) { return Math.abs(x(d.frequency) - x(0)); });
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15388481/d3-js-histogram-with-positive-and-negative-values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there are two problems here:

1. The typos: `.attr("y", function(d, i) { return x(...);})` should now be `.attr("y", function(d, i) { return y(...);})`. Same is true for the scales in your `height` attribute.
2. The change from a 0 base on the X axis to a 0 base on the Y axis. With a zero-based bar on the X axis, the `x` attribute of the bar is `x(0)`. With a 0 based bar on the Y axis, the `y` attribute of the bar is *not* `y(0)`, but `y(value)` (because the "base" of the bar is no longer the leading edge of the rectangle) - so in this code you need to use `Math.max(0, value)` (which will give `y(value)` for positive values) instead of `Math.min(0, value)`:

   ```
   svg.selectAll(".bar")
     // ...snip...
     .attr("y", function(d, i) { return y(Math.max(0, d.frequency));})
     .attr("height", function(d) { return Math.abs(y(d.frequency) - y(0)); });
   ```

See updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pYZn8/5/

Comment: The line       var x0 = Math.max(-d3.min(data), d3.max(data));      no longer contributes since data is no longer an array of numbers and hence x0 is not a number any more.

Comment: thanks! @jing3142: You are correct. My bad for keeping that around.