# D3js Converting a vertical bar chart to horizontal bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

D3jS is pretty intimidating while starting up :(

I managed to get a horizontal bar chart using a JOSN data source. Phew!!!

Now, I need to change the orientation of the chart to a vertical chart and also stacking up the three series in parallel :(:(

Any clue whatsoever would be helpful. I tried looking through a lot of examples (which could have helped immensely) but could not find it.

I am looking to change the chart to something like below(these are the three series).

Deposits | Fee | Lending

EDIT:

I am trying to get this look (of course with just one legend, unlike the repeating one)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNErR.png]

And I am all flummoxed.

This is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sourabhtewari/Gat46/

```
var data = [{
      "MonthYearShortName": "2014-09-13T00:00:00",
      "Product": "Deposits",
      "Actual": 330393232.5,
      "Forecast": 495589848.75,
      "Target": 495589848.75
  }, {
      "MonthYearShortName": "2014-09-13T00:00:00",
      "Product": "Fee Based",
      "Actual": 111868709.42,
      "Forecast": 167803064.13,
      "Target": 167803064.13
  }, {
      "MonthYearShortName": "2014-09-13T00:00:00",
      "Product": "Lending",
      "Actual": 18146873.33,
      "Forecast": 27220309.995,
      "Target": 27220309.995
  }];

  var WIDTH = 860,
      HEIGHT = 500;

  var Y_AXIS_LABEL = "Product";

  var GROUPS = "Product";

  var BARS = ['Actual','Forecast','Target'];

  var margin = {
      top: 20,
      right: 20,
      bottom: 30,
      left: 40
  },
  width = WIDTH - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = HEIGHT - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  var x0 = d3.scale.ordinal()
      .rangeRoundBands([0, width], 0.1);

  var x1 = d3.scale.ordinal();

  var y = d3.scale.linear()
      .range([height, 0]);

  var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
      .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x0)
      .orient("bottom");

  var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y)
      .orient("left")
      .tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"));

  var svg = d3.select("#canvas").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


  data.forEach(function (d) {
      d.bars = BARS.map(function (name) {
          return {
              name: name,
              value: +d[name]
          };
      });
  });

  x0.domain(data.map(function (d) {
      return d[GROUPS];
  }));
  x1.domain(BARS).rangeRoundBands([0, x0.rangeBand()]);
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
      return d3.max(d.bars, function (d) {
          return d.value;
      });
  })]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
      .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(Y_AXIS_LABEL);

  var groups = svg.selectAll(".groups")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "g")
      .attr("transform", function (d) {
      return "translate(" + x0(d[GROUPS]) + ",0)";
  });

  groups.selectAll("rect")
      .data(function (d) {
      return d.bars;
  })
      .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("width", x1.rangeBand())
      .attr("x", function (d) {
      return x1(d.name);
  })
      .attr("y", function (d) {
      return y(d.value);
  })
      .attr("height", function (d) {
      return height - y(d.value);
  })
      .style("fill", function (d) {
      return color(d.name);
  });

  var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
      .data(BARS.slice().reverse())
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("transform", function (d, i) {
      return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")";
  });

  legend.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width - 18)
      .attr("width", 18)
      .attr("height", 18)
      .style("fill", color);

  legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", width - 24)
      .attr("y", 9)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(function (d) {
      return d;
  });
```

Could some D3jS guru please help me. I am all struck up

Comment: Could you please put up an image or a link to a similar chart? I still don't understand what you want your graph to look like.

Comment: @Quinn I have edited the OP to include a sample image. Thanks for looking!

Comment: you can achieve this swapping the axis and height & width of the rectangles

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16202721/d3js-change-vertical-bar-chart-to-horizontal-bar-chart) may help.

Comment: I tried swapping height and width and also x and y axis. http://jsfiddle.net/sourabhtewari/ArpU5/

Am I doing something wrong.