# rotate d3 horizontal bar graph to vertical bar graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Learning d3 integration with Rails right now, and I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.overfitted.com/blog/?p=302).

Is there a standard d3 way to simply flip the graph 90 degrees to the left (so to make the bars vertical) ?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var data = gon.senti_array;

    var x = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(data)])
        .range([0, 420]);

    d3.select(".chart")
      .selectAll("div")
        .data(data)
      .enter().append("div")
        .style("width", function(d) { return x(d) + "px"; })
        .text(function(d) { return d; });
});
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16202721/d3js-change-vertical-bar-chart-to-horizontal-bar-chart

Comment: I think you want to know how to make vertical bar chart her is how you do it http://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/3/