# refactor d3 bar chart to be horizontal bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I was trying to refactor this bar chart in d3 to be a horizontal bar chart. I think I've isolated the three areas that need to be changed:

the original scale declarations:

```
  var x0 = d3.scale.ordinal()
      .rangeRoundBands([0, width], 0.1);

  var x1 = d3.scale.ordinal();

  var y = d3.scale.linear()
      .range([height, 0]);
```

The domain definitions:

```
x0.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.deviceType; }));
x1.domain(deviceClass).rangeRoundBands([0, x0.rangeBand()]);
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d3.max(d.whenPurchased, function(d) { return d.value; }); })]);
```

the rect appending and positioning:

```
device.selectAll("rect")
    .data(function(d) { return d.whenPurchased; })
  .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("width", x1.rangeBand())
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x1(d.device); })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.device); });
```

I can't seem to get the refactoring right and I think that is because I don't exactly get how domain works for x0 and basically not getting that right has a waterfall effect of everything else not working.

I put the full example here: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/hamlinkn/286L7fh0/1/)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16202721/d3js-change-vertical-bar-chart-to-horizontal-bar-chart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick refactor:

```js
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 270},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var y0 = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, height], 0.1);

var y1 = d3.scale.ordinal();

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, width]);

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y0)
    .orient("left");
    // .tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"));

var svg = d3.select("#deviceown-barchart").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var data = d3.csv.parse( d3.select("pre#data").text() );


  var deviceClass = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "deviceType"; });

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.whenPurchased = deviceClass.map(function(device) { return {device: device, value: +d[device]}; });
  });

  y0.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.deviceType; }));
  y1.domain(deviceClass).rangeRoundBands([0, y0.rangeBand()]);
  x.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d3.max(d.whenPurchased, function(d) { return d.value; }); })]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

   svg.append("g")
       .attr("class", "y axis")
       .call(yAxis)
     .append("text")
       .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
       .attr("y", 6)
       .attr("dy", ".71em")
       .style("text-anchor", "end");

  var device = svg.selectAll(".device")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "device")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(0," + y0(d.deviceType) + ")"; });

device.selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) { return d.whenPurchased; })
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("height", y1.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y1(d.device); })
      .attr("x", 0)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.device); })
      .attr("width", 0)
      .transition()
      .duration(1500)
      .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.value); });

  var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
      .data(deviceClass.slice().reverse())
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

  legend.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width - 18)
      .attr("width", 18)
      .attr("height", 18)
      .style("fill", color);

  legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", width - 24)
      .attr("y", 9)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(function(d) { return d; });

// });
```

```css
.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.bar {
  fill: steelblue;
}

.y.axis path {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="deviceown-barchart"></div>

<pre id="data">
deviceType,Within the last 6 months,More than 6 months ago
Netatmo Weather Station,0.14,0.09
Nest Learning Thermostat,0.13,0.14
Philips Hue Connected Bulb,0.13,0.08
Nest Cam,0.12,0.12
Belkin WeMo Switch + Motion,0.09,0.08
Nest Protect,0.08,0.12
Canary,0.08,0.03
Other smart home security device,0.08,0.12
August Smart Lock,0.06,0.07
Other connected home appliance,0.05,0.08
GE/Quirky Aros Smart AC,0.04,0.04
Other smart energy monitor,0,0.03
</pre>
```

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/286L7fh0/2/).

Comment: This is great. I had to turn this into a stacked bar chart, and now I'm wondering how I would be able to animate the rect elements to grow on render, would you know?

Comment: Ah I see you have to initialize whatever "grows" to zero first. Thanks mate.