# How to change the d3 chart data axis

Tags: d3.js

i am using d3.js for using chart. my data charts are showing vertically i dont know how to change the position of the chart can  any one tell me.

here i have attached my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>D3</title>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script>
d3.json("mydata.json",function(data){


var canvas=d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width",500)
        .attr("height",500)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform","translate(50,50)")

canvas.selectAll("rect")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("width",function(d){ return d.age*10})
        .attr("height",48)
        .attr("y",function(d,i){return i*50;})
        .attr("fill","red");

canvas.selectAll("text")
.data(data)
.enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("fill","white")
    .attr("y",function(d,i){return i*50+27;})
    .text(function(d){return d.name})

    })
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

here i have attached my output image. I want change the position vertical to horizontal.

[click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSUt6.jpg)

Comment: This should be helpful to you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16202721/d3js-change-vertical-bar-chart-to-horizontal-bar-chart

Comment: Possible duplicate of [D3js - change Vertical bar chart to Horizontal bar chart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16202721/d3js-change-vertical-bar-chart-to-horizontal-bar-chart)

Answer (score -1):

What you have to do is to change the width and height of the rect elements that you append to the svg.
They also need a horizontal translation instead of a vertical one.
Something like:

```
    .attr("width",48)
    .attr("height",function(d){ return d.age*10})
    .attr("x",function(d,i){return i*50;})
```

Additionally maybe you would like to make them standing instead of hanging and change the text orientation as well.