# how to change the bar chart from horizontal to vertical in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I have done Horizontal Bar Chart using d3.js i tried to do for horizontal but i am not getting it.Can anybody provide me a solution?

This is the code for horizontal bar chart i have done using d3.js

```html
<html>
<body>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<style>
.chart div{

font:10px sans-serif;
background-color:blue;
text-align:right;
padding:10px;

margin:1px;
color:white;


}

</style>

<div class="chart">


</div>



<script>
var data = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42,76];

d3.select(".chart")
.selectAll("div") .data(data)
  .enter().append("div")
.style("width", function(d) { return d*10 + "px"; })
    .text(function(d) { return d; });


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear - whether you are wanting to create a horizontal or a vertical bar chart. In either case, the D3 site https://bl.ocks.org has many examples of the code needed for both types of chart.

The code you have shown is not enough for a chart. You'll need to append a SVG element along with settings for it, code to make it an actual bar chart, to draw your x and y axis, and more. Take a look at the bar charts at that site and you'll have a much clearer idea what you need to add.

The *default* for a bar chart is vertical bars. If you are trying to write a horizontal bar chart, check out this answer [D3js - change Vertical bar chart to Horizontal bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16202721/d3js-change-vertical-bar-chart-to-horizontal-bar-chart).

I don't have the rep to flag as duplicate or comment here, so I hope this is acceptable.