# D3.js - why is this histogram generating a negative width and throwing an error?

Tags: d3.js, histogram

I'm trying to start from Mike Bostock's histogram example:
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3048450

Initially I'm just trying to change the data and domain to get an understanding of how it works and get closer to what I need. But in doing that, my script throws an error due to negative widths on the rects.

**What is this line doing exactly and why does it generate a negative value?**

```
.attr("width", x(data[0].dx) - 1)
```

My fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/rolfsf/p96dH/1/

and my script currently is this:

```
//generate some data with a median of 75
var values = d3.range(1000).map(d3.random.logNormal(Math.log(75), 0.4));

// A formatter for counts.
var formatCount = d3.format(",.0f");

var margin = {top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 30},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([60, 95])
    .range([0, width]);

// Generate a histogram using twenty uniformly-spaced bins.
var data = d3.layout.histogram()
    .bins(x.ticks(7))
    (values);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.y; })])
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var bar = svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.x) + "," + y(d.y) + ")"; });

bar.append("rect")
    .attr("x", 1)
    .attr("width", x(data[0].dx) - 1)
    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.y); });

bar.append("text")
    .attr("dy", ".75em")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("x", x(data[0].dx) / 2)
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(d) { return formatCount(d.y); });

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);
```

UPDATE: The answer in this question: [D3 Histogram with negative values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20184194/d3-histogram-with-negative-values?rq=1) actually gives me the chart layout I wanted, though Lars is correct that my domain function is causing problems.

an updated fiddle is here (note that due to the domain issue, the first and last bars have incorrect heights) http://jsfiddle.net/rolfsf/p96dH/3/

I replaced my width function with the barWidth variable:

```
var numbins = data.length;
var barWidth = width/numbins - 1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simply the way you've set up your `x` scale. You're assuming that all values are going to be in the interval (60,95), which they are not. For values smaller than 60, you get negative numbers.

You can fix this easily by getting the actual extent of the data for the domain:

```
var x = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain(d3.extent(data))
  .range([0, width]);
```

Comment: Thanks Lars - I had narrowed the domain because I wanted to look at a subset of the full data set, but I guess I was mis-using the domain function.  I still would like to know what that width function is doing - I just don't really understand it well enough.

Comment: You're taking a data point and mapping it to the output range using the scale function. That is, the smallest point in the domain is mapped to the smallest in the range and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, it is due to the domain; the reason it works in Mike's example is that the domain minimum he uses is 0.

A better approach would be to do the following, replace every occurrence of

```
x(data[0].dx) - 1
```

with

```
x(60 + data[0].dx) - 1
```

More, generally, you can define your x scale with:

```
var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain(d3.extent(data))
    .range([0, width]);
```

And then the above snippets (setting bar width), become:

```
x(d3.min(datasetBars) + data[0].dx) - 1)
```