# How to randomly apply bar color, and show negative value, and show tooltip for the bar value

Tags: javascript, ember.js, d3.js

How to randomly apply bar  color, and  show negative value?

I tried to add color:red attribute in the hash, but it didn't work.

And how to show negative value ?

The last is, when I move mouse on the bar I want to show the tooltip. How to do it ?

Thanks very much..

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    // Ember.A() just a way to define an Ember
    return Ember.A([
      Ember.Object.create({'letter':'Automating working hours', 'num':0, "color": "red" }),
      Ember.Object.create({'letter':'Saving hours/round', 'num':0, "color": "yellow" }),
      Ember.Object.create({'letter':'Saving hours/year', 'num':0 }),
    ]);
  }
});


App.BarChartComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'svg',
  attributeBindings: 'width height'.w(),

  draw: function(){
    var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40};
    var width = this.get('width') - margin.left - margin.right;
    var height = this.get('height') - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    var data = this.get('data');
    var svg = d3.select(this.get('element'));

    var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], 0.1);
    var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient('bottom');
    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient('left');
    var color = d3.scale.ordinal().range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00", "red", "green"]);


    x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.letter; }));
    y0=d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.num; })
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.num; })]);
    // y.domain([-y0,y0]).nice();

    svg = svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis)
      .append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 6)
        .attr("dy", ".71em")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text("Hours");

    svg.selectAll(".bar")
        .data(data)
      .enter().append("rect")
        .attr("class", "bar")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.letter); })
        .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
        .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.num); })
        .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.num); })
        /********* add class name on bar **********/ 

        /********* add class name on bar **********/

  }.on('didInsertElement')
```

Comment: Concerning bar with negative values, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10127402/bar-chart-with-negative-values) answer may be useful. It would be good to have your working code at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so somebody can help you.

Comment: Your question is composed of 3 different questions.