# Creating an axis with absolute value in d3

Tags: svg, d3.js

I have created a bar chart with negative values in d3. The chart displays the difference in score between two teams over a series of games so if Team A won by three points over team B, the data point is -3. If Team B won by three, the data point is 3.

The graph itself is fine but I would like the axis to reflect the absolute value of the data point. I tried:

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(Math.abs(x))
    .orient("top");
```

but that didn't seem to do the trick. Any ideas are welcomed.

Thanks,
Jon

Comment: The setup you have for the axis doesn't seem quite right to me.  `scale` should be linked back to a `d3.scale` function, so something like `d3.scale.linear()`.  The d3 scale will then have the output `range` and an input `domain`.  You would need to calculate the domain using something like `d3.extent(data, function(d) { return Math.abs(d); }).`  To see this all inaction have a look at this [bl.ock](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955).

Comment: Sorry. I knew I didn't make this clear. I'm relatively new to the whole coding thing. I have a d3.scale.linear() and a domain calculated. The graph itself draws fine. What I'm trying to do is get the axis labeled so instead of it showing -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3 it shows 3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3 even though the graph itself will be drawing negative bard. In essence, this chart: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10127402/bar-chart-with-negative-values but with both sides of the axis showing positive numbers.

Comment: Ah, that's a different thing altogether.  How about using an ordinal scale somehow.  Or you could turnoff the labels from the axis, compute the positions of the numbers `[3,2,1,0,1,2,3]` and write a custom axis label to write them there.  Computing the positions is easy since you already have the axis.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Finally was able to get back working on this today and figured out the solution once you mentioned the custom axis. Used .tickFormat(Math.abs) and that did the trick. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is not documented but it's possible to pass a function to `tickFormat`, this way:

```
tickFormat(Math.abs)
```

You can even make more complex formatting, such as:

```
tickFormat(function (v) {
    return Math.abs(v) + '%';
})
```

Looking at the [`tickFormat`'s source code](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/src/tickFormat.js), I couldn't find any evidence of this behavior. So, it doesn't look like this is even expected, but it worked anyway. This is just a guess, but maybe the passed function is called somewhere in the underlying layer.

**P.S.**: The OP already answered this question [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29023687/creating-an-axis-with-absolute-value-in-d3#comment46592074_29023687), but I'm posting it here to make it easier for others to find it.